# How to sync my Wndows XP clock?

Tags: windows-xp, sync, date-time

I was wondering how to sync my Windows XP clock? When I try to sync with servers (time.windows.com or time.nist.gov) it fails to sync..
Do you know any good server or solution?

Comment: Ummm... Yeah... Do you get any error messages? How do you know it's not synching? Is your TZ set correctly? Do you have the appropariate DST patches installed?

Comment: It says in the clock window: The time sample was rejected because: The peer's stratum is less than the host's stratum.

Comment: Do you have the relevant DST updates installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you've been given by Windows often occurs on DST changes (but does occur sometimes at other times), it's just that the default Microsoft NTP servers are out of sync (that's not technically correct, but it should help explain it :) ). It probably indicates that you're behind the time being provided by the host's reference clock.

Microsoft servers often have this problem. The best way to alleviate problems like this is to switch to a more reliable time server, I use utcnist.colorado.edu.

I'm not exactly a wizard with NTP though, so some of this may not have incredible technical accuracy, but the end result should be satisfactory. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Karen's Time Sync](http://www.karenware.com/powertools/ptsync.asp). works like a charm, and you can set the time server it asks and the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Use 0.pool.ntp.org - has always worked for me.